# Java Generate Html pages

Tags: java, javascript, html

I am working on a project that a user can generate a form.

I am using / javascript / java < STS /tomcat 
Meaning  the user enters the website and selects fields / string/ dropdown/ radio button etc.

when he clicks save on the bottom the different fields are saved in the database(mysql)
this can be done multiple times creating multiple forms.

**Here** is the problem 
I want from this form to be able generate a page where a different user can enter and fill this generated forms. 
( looking for code or reference materials to read or any kind of help)

Comment: http://ckeditor.com/ can be used to generate forms. but sill the action page is a problem. That you have to handle yourself.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not the right place to ask for reference materials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We did this recently in our project. Basically the forms are driven by database. So for ex: a form is made up of fields. We used JSF TO GENERATE TAGS ON BASIS OF FORM BACKING BEAN PROPERTY.

Hope this helps